# Getting AccessDenied on s3api copy-object when IAM role allows it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My IAM permissions look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The command I am trying to run is

```
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source 2021/my_dump.sql --key test.text --bucket bucket-name
```

The error that I get back is

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied
```

Interestingly enough if I do

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/2021/2021/my_dump.sql s3://bucket-name/ test.text
```

Then there is no problem. I am trying to use `aws s3api copy-object`so I don't need to download then re-upload every file.

Comment: I think the reason that you see AccessDenied is because you have mistakenly made a request to copy an object from a bucket named `2021` and your credentials have no permissions for that bucket.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the source bucket in `--copy-source`

```
aws s3api copy-object --copy-source source-bucket/2021/my_dump.sql --key 2021/my_dump.sql --bucket destination-bucket
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why using aws s3 cp is a lot faster than aws s3api copy-object ? aws s3api copy-object takes about 31 seconds and sws s3 cp takes 11. I would think the file not coming to my PC and back would be fastre.

Comment: That would be related to what's the hood, s3 cp uses UploadPart maybe it handles the copy process better.